# export variable within `/bin/bash -c`

Tags: bash, export, quoting

I'm trying to export variable within the `/bin/bash -c` command.

This results in empty output:

```
/bin/bash -c "export FOO=foo; echo $FOO"
```

What would be the proper way to do that?

Comment: What's the purpose of this anyway? The purpose of `export` is to make the variable available to subprocesses but `echo` is a shell built-in so there are no subprocesses of this shell. And obviously, the child shell you run cannot affect its parent's variables directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you double-quoted the command,
the `$FOO` got evaluated in your current shell,
not by the `/bin/bash -c`.
That is, what actually got executed was this:

```
/bin/bash -c 'export FOO=foo; echo '
```

Enclose in single-quotes:

```
/bin/bash -c 'export FOO=foo; echo $FOO'
```

An equivalent shorter form:

```
FOO=foo /bin/bash -c 'echo $FOO'
```